# Where are image data stored and how to gain access to it

Tags: javascript, html

The html code

```
<html>
<img src="https://google.com/image.jpg"> 
</html>
```

loads the image.jpg file, say 1Mb in size, onto device memory somewhere.

How can we gain access the raw binary contents of that particular 1Mb sized file that is loaded, for instance for purposes of image editing?

Ideally, I would love to be able to copy the entire jpg file to a new byte-array[] which can then be edited as we like.

Any help much appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fetch` to manually fetch the image and read its buffer content;

```
fetch('https://google.com/image.jpg')
.then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
```